# Postgres server not starting anymore

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

My postgres was working previously, but for some reason does not work anymore. I have tried several different searches in stack overflow and other sites, and after coming up with the same results and reading the same pages over and over again, without any success, it was time to post a new question.

Trying to run my rails project on the local host raises the following error message: `could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

The server is not running at all, as indicated by the following output from `ps -fu postgres`:

`postgres 23969 23968  0 09:54 pts/25   00:00:00 -bash`

**Error messages that I'm getting:**

- When running as the "postgres" user, executing `psql` results in:

`psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

- When trying to start postgres:

---

**Other things I have tried:**

- Executing `postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &` (as indicated by the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/server-start.html)) outputs: `[1] 24670`. But the server still doesn't run.
- I also tried starting the  server via `service postgres start`. This prompts me to my password to authenticate me as the user (it says `Authentication is required to start 'postgres.service'.`) My login succeeds (`==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===`)but then it says `Failed to start postgres.service: Unit postgres.service not found.`
- I tried restarting the server (following [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/397108/how-to-configure-postgresql-ubuntu) using `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`), which in the past did fix postgres, but now simply prompts `Restarting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.` However, now I try to start the server again, and nothing has changed.
- The problem does not seem to be any postmaster.pid file that I need to remove. After going through the same process that [this user did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x), nothing was found when running `sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -ls`
- I have tried a clean install, and it still doesn't work. Nothing has changed, and the same error messages are appearing.

After removing postgres (following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu)), I went through the [digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04) up to the point where it says  "You can now access a Postgres prompt immediately by typing: `psql`".

**Other possible factors:** (I am at my wit's end, so I'm listing any possible factor that comes to mind)

1. I am running Ubuntu Xenial (16.04), and postgresql 9.5
2. I recently moved and am using a new Internet provider. I'm not sure why this would be an issue, but it did require me to change other settings (specifically, to deploy my rails project locally, instead of localhost:3000 I was using my inet addr. In other words, "http://:3000" (where  is the number provided for inet by ifconfig). But after moving to a new Internet provider, my inet addr changed.
3. [Update] Log files:

`LOG: could not bind IPv4 socket: Cannot assign requested address
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets`

At this point I spent several hours to no avail... Please help!!

Comment: can you paste the result of `pg_lsclusters`

Comment: 9.5 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log

Comment: also paste for `netstat -tulpn | grep :5432`

Comment: When I run that, I get `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)`. when I run it using sudo, I get `sudo: unable to resolve host <my_machine> `

Comment: my /etc/hosts has the old inet address. This might be the problem

Comment: yeah, it might be.

Comment: I changed the number for my_machine to the new inet address (I'm assuming it shouldn't just be 127.0.0.1?). Now it outputs `tcp        0      0 <my_inet_addr>:5432      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3535/postgres `. Server still doesn't seem to work. Or do I need to change the address for the localhost?

Comment: Did you reboot? https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none/177381

Comment: I did, but what ultimately resolve the issue is that I had changed /etc/hosts back to the default setting (from 127.0.0.1 For the local host and 127.0.1.1 for my machine). Will post a complete explanation below. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you knew to do `netstat -tulpn | grep :5432`, so I know for future reference?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is any process on 5432 port. Glad, that my comment could help. Can you uplvote my comment. Thanks

Comment: Hi - this comment is for the next person with this problem.  I was getting this error on a _reinstall_.  I had previously `remove`-d postgres. In my case the configuration files did not all have owner: "`postgres`".  So `start` was giving me: "`Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)`" errors.  Why? File owner.  Evidently I'd edited a file and not reset the ownership.  _tsk, tsk tsk_

Comment: PS.  thanks for all those questions -- they are a great help when you want to troubleshoot this kind of thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /etc/hosts file was incorrectly configured, due to some changes to that file previously. It did not cause trouble immediately, but for some reason changing the file back to defaults (i.e., 127.0.0.1 for the local host and 127.0.1.1 for my machine) solved the problem.

This was discovered by running `netstat -tulpn | grep :5432`, which gave the following error output: `sudo: unable to resolve host <my_machine>`. This pointed to the fact that there was a problem with the /etc/hosts file.

For a helpful resource, see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none/177381).

Comment: Credit to Nikhil for pointing me to the answer.

Comment: I'm fairly satisfied. I have to wait 2 days though.

However, it would be nice to know why this solution actually worked (i.e., why this problem came up now rather than a few weeks ago when I 1st changed my /etc/hosts file). Also, any general principles on when to use `netstat `?